# TYPO3 11 content element Plain HTML with <style>

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

TYPO3 11.5.4

I want to add a Plain HTML content element to a page, e.g.:

```
<style type="text/css">
  h1#testheader { font-weight: bold; }
</style>
<h1 id="testheader">
  Header
</h1>
```

(just as a simplified example)

But rendered output is:

```
<style type="text/css"> h1#testheader { font-weight: bold; } </style>
Header
```

I thought that style is allowed because I set:

```
lib.parseFunc.allowTags = ...,style,...
lib.parseFunc_RTE.allowTags = ...,style,...
```

but it doesn't work.
Setting

```
lib.parseFunc.htmlSanitize = 0
```

helps but is there something better to allow `<style>` in Plain HTML content elements?

EDIT:
Looking into the DB entry the html tags are not encoded, so no "<" or ">" instead of "<" and ">", so it's not an issue of the RTE.

Comment: Good question and self-answer! I'd like to do achieve same thing with the `<map>` and `<area>` HTML tags, to allow editors to  create old-school clickable imagemaps. (Perhaps I'll post again if your approach works for me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research (hours of hours again invested) I come to the conclusion that the only way is to extend the HTMLSanitizer.

The following sources have been used for this solution:

https://punkt.de/de/blog/2021/htmlsanitizer-in-typo3.html
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.5.x/Important-94484-IntroduceHTMLSanitizer.html
https://gist.github.com/ohader/2239dab247e18d23e677fd1b816f4fd5

The complete solution to allow `<style>`,`<script>` and `<iframe>` is shown below.

**Still I am not able to allow `<font>` with this approach!**

It's implemented in a local site package (gpcf_theme) and composer is used.

Add `<style>`,`<script>` and `<iframe>` to

```
lib.parseFunc.allowTags = ... style, ..., iframe, script, ...
```

in the TypoScript part of the site package.

`style` seems to be standard and is already part of this list.

The path to the local site package is:

```
local_packages/gpcf_theme
```

with a symbolic link to it from:

```
public/typo3conf/ext/gpcf_theme -> ../../../local_packages/gpcf_theme
```

These are the important file changes:

*local_packages/gpcf_theme/composer.json:*

```
{
        "name": "oheil/gpcf_theme",
        ...
        "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                        "Oheil\\GpcfTheme\\": "Classes/"
                }
        },
        ...
}
```

*local_packages/gpcf_theme/ext_localconf.php:*

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die();

...
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['htmlSanitizer']['default'] = \Oheil\GpcfTheme\MyDefaultBuilder::class;
...
```

*local_packages/gpcf_theme/Classes/MyDefaultBuilder.php*

```
<?php

namespace Oheil\GpcfTheme;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Html\DefaultSanitizerBuilder;
use TYPO3\HtmlSanitizer\Behavior;
use TYPO3\HtmlSanitizer\Behavior\Attr;
use TYPO3\HtmlSanitizer\Behavior\Tag;

class MyDefaultBuilder extends \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Html\DefaultSanitizerBuilder
{
    protected function createBehavior(): \TYPO3\HtmlSanitizer\Behavior
    {
        // https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.5.x/Important-94484-IntroduceHTMLSanitizer.html

        return parent::createBehavior()
                ->withName('common')
                ->withTags(
                        (new Tag(
                                'style',
                                Tag::ALLOW_CHILDREN + Behavior::ENCODE_INVALID_TAG
                        ))->addAttrs(
                                (new Attr('type')),
                                ...$this->globalAttrs
                        ),
                        (new Tag(
                                'iframe',
                                Tag::ALLOW_CHILDREN
                        ))->addAttrs(
                                ...array_merge(
                                        $this->globalAttrs,
                                        [$this->srcAttr],
                                        $this->createAttrs('scrolling', 'marginwidth', 'marginheight', 'frameborder', 'vspace', 'hspace', 'height', 'width')
                                )
                        ),
                        (new Tag(
                                'script',
                                Tag::ALLOW_CHILDREN
                        ))->addAttrs(
                                ...array_merge(
                                        $this->globalAttrs,
                                        [$this->srcAttr]
                                )
                        ),
                        // more tags...
        );
    }
}
```

After these changes of course you need to clear the TYPO3 cache and (not sure here) you need to do:

```
composer remove "oheil/gpcf_theme"
composer require "oheil/gpcf_theme"
```

The above is working now, but I am still happy for any expert to give some more insights in what is wrong or can be done better, perhaps easier?

And why does this not work for `<font>` ?
Example:

```
<font class="font713099">Some Text</font>
```